# Separating images of specific dates

Tags: google-earth-engine

I first filtered the required images and merged them. Now, I need only the images of these dates: `['2001-03-03', '2006-02-13', '2011-01-10', '2011-03-15', '2016-02-20', '2021-03-18']`. I tried the following code but it did not work.

```
//landsat 8
var landsat8 = L8
.filterBounds(table)
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 5))
.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1, 1, 'month'))
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 112))
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 82));

print(landsat8)

//Landsat 9
var landsat9 = L9
.filterBounds(table)
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 5))
.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1, 1,"month"))
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 112))
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 82));

var landsat7 = L7
.filterDate('2001', '2021')
.filterBounds(table)
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 5))
.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1,3,"month"))
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 112))
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 82));

var merg89 = landsat9.merge(landsat8); 
var LST89 = merg89.map(tir)


// Define the dates of interest
var dates = ['2001-03-03', '2006-02-13', '2011-01-10', '2011-03-15', '2016-02-20', '2021-03-18'];

var filteredCollection = Allimage.filterDate(ee.Date(dates[0]), ee.Date(dates[5]));

var selectedImages = filteredCollection.filter(ee.Filter.date(ee.Date(dates[0]), ee.Date(dates[5])).filterBounds(geometry));

print('Selected Images:', selectedImages);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine a number of `ee.Filter.date()` date range filters with an `ee.Filter.or()` filter. It has the advantage of not requiring you to map over the unfiltered collection to add a date property.

```
var dateFilters = dates.map(function (date) {
  return ee.Filter.date(ee.Date(date).getRange('day'))
})
var filter = ee.Filter.or.apply(this, dateFilters)
var filteredCollection = collection.filter(filter)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/d7f317eecf768c5aab1784a0cce7cdec

Answer (score 1):

Landsat images have a `system:time_start` property giving you the acquisition date/time.

For example, you can query a couple of image acquisition times as below:

```js
print("Images acquisition dateTimes in milliseconds:")
print(landsat8.limit(5).aggregate_array("system:time_start"))
```

Since you are interested in selecting images that match a given date, and not datetime, we can define a new property called `date`, for example one way to do this:

```js
function assignDate(image){
  var dateTime=image.date()
  var y=dateTime.get("year")
  var m=dateTime.get("month")
  var d=dateTime.get("day")
  return image.set(
    {
      date: ee.Date.fromYMD(y,m,d)
    })
}
landsat8 = landsat8.map(assignDate)
```

Finally, you could apply a `ee.Filter.inList` to filter the collection to specific dates:

```js
// Define the dates of interest
var dates = ['2021-02-14', '2021-04-03'];
var ee_dates = dates.map(function(d){return ee.Date(d)})
var selected_images = landsat8
.filter(ee.Filter.inList("date",ee_dates))
```

Note that I simplified your example to only solve the problem of selecting specific dates: https://code.earthengine.google.com/89fa697c27425cc3e9f53e4b4e22817d

Comment: Thank you for sharing this code. It was really helpful.